# How to check and update mySQL with swift?

Tags: mysql, swift, class, switch-statement, completionhandler

I have some code that should check if some id's exist and update DB by adding new rows in multiple tables. However I can't get it to work and my code is definitely not optimal.

Could you please help me with getting it to work and show me the proper methods for doing this?

Here is my class that is used to check and update the DB:

```
class UpdatePlanDB{
    
    private var UserPlanCheckIsGood : Bool = false
    private var PlanCheckIsGood : Bool = false
    private var bothChecked : Int = 0
    
    func getNewPlanId(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void){
        getLowestPlanId(){ result in
                var lowestPlanId : Int = 2
                switch(result){
                case .success(let res):
                    lowestPlanId = res
                case .failure(let err):
                    completionHandler(.failure(err))
                }
                if(lowestPlanId >= 2){
                    completionHandler(.success(lowestPlanId - 1))
                }else{
                    var highestPlanId : Int = 0
                    self.getHeighestPlanId(){ resultH in
                        switch(resultH){
                        case .success(let res):
                            highestPlanId = res
                        case .failure(let error):
                            completionHandler(.failure(error))
                        }
                        completionHandler(.success(highestPlanId + 1))
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
    func getLowestPlanId(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL_GET_GET_LOWEST_PLAN_ID)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        //request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
                return
            }else if let data = data {
                if var jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    jsonString = jsonString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
                    completionHandler(.success(Int(jsonString)!))
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
    
    func getHeighestPlanId(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL_GET_GET_HIGHEST_PLAN_ID)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        //request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
                return
            }else if let data = data {
                if var jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    jsonString = jsonString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
                    completionHandler(.success(Int(jsonString)!))
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
    
    func checkIdDoesNotExist(planId: Int, tableName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL_CHECK_PLAN_ID_EXISTS)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let postString = "planId=\(planId)&tableName=\(tableName)"
        
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
                return
            }else if let data = data {
                if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    if(jsonString == "0 results"){
                        completionHandler(.success(true))
                       
                    }else{
                        completionHandler(.success(false))
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
    
    func addToUserPlans(planId: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void){
        checkIdDoesNotExist(planId: planId, tableName: "UserPlans"){ result in
            switch(result){
            case .success(let res):
                self.UserPlanCheckIsGood = res
                self.bothChecked += 1
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
                self.UserPlanCheckIsGood = false
                self.bothChecked += 1
            }
        }
        
        checkIdDoesNotExist(planId: planId, tableName: "Plans"){ result in
            switch(result){
            case .success(let res):
                self.PlanCheckIsGood = res
                self.bothChecked += 1
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
                self.PlanCheckIsGood = false
                self.bothChecked += 1
            }
        }
        
        while(bothChecked != 2){
            print("waiting")
        }
        
        if(PlanCheckIsGood && UserPlanCheckIsGood){
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL_ADD_USER_PLANS)! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "userId=\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "None")&planId=\(planId)"
            
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
                    return
                }else if let data = data {
                    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        if(jsonString == "true"){
                            completionHandler(.success(true))
                        }else{
                            completionHandler(.success(false))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }else{
            completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
        }
    }
    
    func addPlan(planId: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void){
        if(PlanCheckIsGood && UserPlanCheckIsGood){
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL_ADD_PLAN)! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "userId=\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "None")&planId=\(planId)"
            
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
                    return
                }else if let data = data {
                    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        if(jsonString == "true"){
                            completionHandler(.success(true))
                        }else{
                            completionHandler(.success(false))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }else{
            completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.badURL))
        }
    }
    
    func addProgressRow(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void){
        
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
let newUpdate = UpdatePlanDB()
newUpdate.getNewPlanId(){result in
    switch(result){
    case .success(let res):
        newUpdate.addPlan(planId: res){ result2 in
            switch(result2){
            case .success(let res2):
                print(String(describing: res2))
            case .failure(let err2):
                print(err2)
            }
        }
                                                    
        newUpdate.addToUserPlans(planId: res){ result2 in
            switch(result2){
            case .success(let res2):
                print(String(describing: res2))
            case .failure(let err2):
                print(err2)
            }
        }
    case .failure(let err):
        print(err , "---------------------------")
    }
}
```

The following functions work fine: getNewPlanId(), getLowestPlanId(), getHeighestPlanId() and checkIdDoesNotExist().

Where the code is run it should return "true" twice if it succeeded.
Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: "I can't get it to work" is not a problem description. What happens when this code is run? Why is that wrong? What should happen instead?

Comment: It should update my DB and print a message saying that it completed. You can't run it because I haven't posted all the php code that is run by calling the address stored in "URL_GET_GET_LOWEST_PLAN_ID" as a string

Comment: "It should update my DB and print a message saying that it completed." But is there any message in console beforehand? There are a few URL calls, what's happening? Is one of the call at least working? Which one? Which one is failing? What's the output?

Comment: I have updated the question to answer your questions.